# Tor browser is not connecting in stead of using tor bridges

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, censorship, obfsproxy

Sir I am connecting to tor network using tor bridges since direct connection with tor is blocked in our area.But what i got message after connection failed is provided below;

```
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.473 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.473 [WARN] Pluggable transport proxy (obfs2,obfs3 exec Tor\PluggableTransports\obfsproxy managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.474 [WARN] Pluggable transport proxy (flashproxy exec Tor\PluggableTransports\flashproxy-client --register :0 :9000) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.474 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.474 [WARN] Pluggable transport proxy (obfs2,obfs3 exec Tor\PluggableTransports\obfsproxy managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.474 [WARN] Pluggable transport proxy (flashproxy exec Tor\PluggableTransports\flashproxy-client --register :0 :9000) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.474 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.474 [WARN] Pluggable transport proxy (obfs2,obfs3 exec Tor\PluggableTransports\obfsproxy managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.474 [WARN] Pluggable transport proxy (flashproxy exec Tor\PluggableTransports\flashproxy-client --register :0 :9000) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.474 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.474 [WARN] Pluggable transport proxy (obfs2,obfs3 exec Tor\PluggableTransports\obfsproxy managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.474 [WARN] Pluggable transport proxy (flashproxy exec Tor\PluggableTransports\flashproxy-client --register :0 :9000) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.474 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "G:\tor\Tor with scramblesuit\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.514 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server. 
3/18/2014 18:23:34 PM.514 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. 
3/18/2014 18:28:36 PM.492 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn) 
3/18/2014 18:28:36 PM.492 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
3/18/2014 18:28:36 PM.493 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
3/18/2014 18:28:49 PM.736 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 2; recommendation warn) 
3/18/2014 18:28:49 PM.736 [WARN] 2 connections have failed: 
3/18/2014 18:28:49 PM.736 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
```

I am using tor bundle from the given weblin https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en

Comment: i AM UNABLE to read the captcha code which is quite illegible and can't be comprehended. So I always fail to use bridges. TOR website should use some other captcha which should show clear fonts. See for example the clear captcha code shown by facebook and Vfemail.net.

Comment: Even iam experiencing the same problems, irrespective of the bridges, error was stated as pluggable transport proxy supporting 'flashproxy'
:(

Comment: How did you configure it? Do you know the [Flashproxy HOWTO](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/FlashProxyHowto)?

Comment: The question seems abandoned. Thus I'll close it. If you have further additions, please [edit](https://tor.stackexchange.com/posts/1738/edit) the question and it can be reopened.